# How to use my Huawei E3531i dongle in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, usb-modem, huawei

I am using KDE OS in my desktop, and I am trying to connect my Huawei dongle for more than a year now. I have tried several solutions available in different help forums. But till now i could not either install Mobile Partner nor connect to internet using my dongle. the modfel i am using is Huawei E3531i - 2.

Comment: check out https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/help-using-3g-usb-dongle-through-wwan-interface-rather-than-ppp-4175537653/